# Signal Server Error: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, jersey

I was trying to install signal server v 0.93, the server has running. then i use Signal Android v4.17, when i Running the android app, it can send sms. but when i submit verification code, the server return the following error,  :

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class io.dropwizard.jersey.validation.ValidationErrorMessage, genericType=class io.dropwizard.jersey.validation.ValidationErrorMessage.
! at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:247) ~[TextSecureServer-0.93.jar:0.93]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162) ~[TextSecureServer-0.93.jar:0.93]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106) ~[TextSecureServer-0.93.jar:0.93]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162) ~[TextSecureServer-0.93.jar:0.93]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:86) ~[TextSecureServer-0.93.jar:0.93]
```

I was trying to install android version 2.23, it works. but i want to use the latest signal android app. any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Current version of [Signal-Server](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Server) is 2.26, and you are trying to use 0.93 which is 3 years old. I assume that you pulled source code using GitHub tag but you should checkout from master and use latest version

Comment: I was trying signal v2.26 but it less documentation about config yml.. I always getting error because of config yml..  Anyone has sample of latest signal configuration?